# How to create a dynamically created link helper in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a folder with about 10 images in them that are pulled at random on my webpage. Currently the code looks like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/products/default_products/default_product_#{rand(1..9)}.jpg"), product%>
```

That works fine on development but on production when the name of the jpeg gets changed it does not work. It generates a link that looks like this:

```
/assets/products/default_products/default_product_6.jpg
```

When all of the images in fact have been renamed to something like this:

```
default_product_3-af2af1f642a10926ed5cfb29aeb780e6.jpg
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint(`af2af1f642a10926ed5cfb29aeb780e`) into each filename so that the file is cached by the web browser.

[From documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> Fingerprinting is enabled by default for production and disabled for
>   all other environments. You can enable or disable it in your
>   configuration through the config.assets.digest option.

Comment: Seems overkill to disable fingerprinting for my whole site just for this one small issue. Isn't there a way I could disable it on a per-file basis? Or somehow get my random generator to pick up on the fingerprinted name?

Answer (score 0):

what if you make an array of existing images, and then randomly select one of them rather than generating the file names?

```
pictures = %w(pic_1 pic_2 pic_3)

image_tag("/path/to/files/#{pictures.sample}")
```

this way you can keep fingerprinting.

Comment: Good idea but that didn't work, unfortunately. Same problem where the generated link doesn't get the fingerprint

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... nevermind. My original code actually works I just needed to remove the '/assets/' part from the link_tag helper.

So this works with fingerprinting:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("products/default_products/default_product_#{rand(1..9)}.jpg"), product%>
```